# Regex breakdown

Tags: regex

Can someone help me with this regex password validation for rails?

It currently is set to ensure:

- Password should contain at least one integer.
- Password should contain at least one alphabet(either in lowercase or uppercase).
- Password can
  have special characters from 20 to 7E
  ascii values.
- Password should be
  minimum of 8 and maximum of 40
  characters long.

**How can I remove the one single decimal digit rule?**

`/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*([a-z]|[A-Z]))([\x20-\x7E]){8,40}$/`

Comment: This is totally one of those areas where regexes should NOT be applied.

Comment: Interesting, how should I validate password requirements?

Comment: @Juliet, agree that regexes are often misused. But I disagree that this is *totally one of those* times. I encourage you to post an answer on how this *should* be done.

Comment: I'm trying to save errors to the flash, not using JavaScript validation. Perhaps I can figure something else out in Ruby. Thanks :)

Comment: Don’t say integer when you mean one single decimal digit between "0" and "9".  After all, -23509203598209358092859028354092384 is also an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to recommend against a monolithic regex to test all of your password requirements. It seems much easier to write them as lots of small statements:

```
if(password.length >= 8 &&
   password.length <= 40 &&
   password.contains('\d') &&
   password.contains('[a-zA-Z]') &&
   password.contains('^[\x20-\x7E]$'))
   return true
else
   return false
```

Its a bit more self-documenting to future maintainers, and a lot easier on the eyes.

Comment: Agree about the self-documentation. But this still uses regexes. 3 of them actually. You said this is where *regexed should not be applied.*

Answer (score 1):

\d represents all number digits. You want:

```
/^(?=.*([a-z]|[A-Z]))([\x20-\x7E]){8,40}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?=.*([a-z]|[A-Z]))([\x20-\x7E]){8,40}$/
```